# How to integrate TestRail with Azure DevOps Pipeline?

Tags: azure-devops, continuous-integration, azure-pipelines, cypress, testrail

I run CI/CD pipeline on Azure DevOps and generate Junit xml files with test results. By the way, I use Cypress framework for my tests.

Is there any way to ingest Junit results into TestRail 7.5 and publish test results in "Test Runs and Results" tab in TestRail?

Actually, what I would like to achieve is to generate new runs on TestRail and push the test results after each run on pipeline.

Can anyone that has done it previously help me, please?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to have a look at [Railflow](https://railflow.io/) which provides exact functionality you want. It is a commercial tool but it provides free support for JUnit report uploading into TestRail.

P.S. I'm developer at Railflow